# How do listen to radio online

Tags: webapp-rec, streaming

How do I receive an online live radio broadcast feed in the U.S. using a laptop with Windows Vista?

Answer (score 3):

Most sites will have a flash-based player available, so all you really need is a browser, flash player plugin, and some speakers.

Example: http://www.live365.com/index.live

http://www.edge.ca/ (click "Listen Live" at the top)

Comment: Many also use arguably more convenient [SHOUTcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHOUTcast) streams, for which you need a supporting client.

Comment: Depends how you define "convenient". Being in IT I have to hop around many different machines all day. 99% have flash player so I pop open a browser and I'm back listening to the radio station, no software install needed.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's iTunes is a free download, runs on Vista and receives Internet radio stations.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://di.fm

No additional software required.